# Use r sqldf select LIKE for subset data with many IDs

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a short question concerning the sqldf package in R.

I want to subset data for different IDs in one column. The IDs are Article DOIs and since I am filtering for Journals, I only want to sort for the Journal-identifying part of the DOI.

This works for a single ID:

```
newdata <- sqldf("select * from data where column1 LIKE '%stringcontent%')
```

An extension works for multiple ID types:

```
newdata <- sqldf("select * from data where column1 LIKE '%stringcontent1%'
                  or column1 LIKE '%stringcontent2%'
                  or column1 LIKE '%stringcontent3%')
```

Is there any possibility to use stringcontent1, stringcontent2 and stringcontent3 as a vector for simplifying the command? I have a big dataset with around 200 IDs and this would be much easier than add every single ID.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Questions should include test data and desired output.  See instructions at top of [tag:r] tag.

Answer (score 2):

Create a target table of strings and then join it to the main table d.  We have shown test tables in the Note at the end.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select d.* 
  from data d join target t on d.x like '%' || t.string || '%'")
##                    x
## 1 x stringcontent1 y
```

This would also work:

```
sqldf("select d.* from data d join target t on instr(d.x, t.string)")
```

### Note

```
target <- structure(list(string = c("stringcontent1", "stringcontent2", 
  "stringcontent3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

data  <- structure(list(x = c("x stringcontent1 y", "xx stringcontent9 yy", 
"def")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```